# Building Go binaries without debugging info

Tags: go

Is it possible to build go binary so that it doesn't show stack-trace on panic and doesn't contain any source code paths etc?

I'm currently using ld-flags "-w" and "-s" but resulting binary still contains some unneeded paths and shows unneeded stack trace on panic.

There is a issue about this thing (https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3467) but it is old and hasn't been updated for a while (and I don't have slightest idea what "patching runtime" in one of issues comments means).

Comment: This topic has been beaten to death already on the `go-nuts` mailing list; [this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/Xr2Zsa0YfKs/discussion) is a relatively recent such discussion.

Comment: You hence might chime in the `golang-dev` mailing list trying to discuss if it might be possible to trim `$GOROOT` from filenames embedded into the executable at build phase as proposed in [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6819).

Comment: Oh, and to may be recap what's stated in the ML thread I've referenced: there's no working way to remove this information from programs generated by the Go `gc` suite because the runtime relies on this information (i.e. it's not only for the user contemplating the printout resulting from an unhandled `panic()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to do this right now.

The comment about patching the runtime means that is currently the only way to disable that output. The runtime is what prints the stack traces on panic, and the segfault addresses; and you'd have to write a patch to disable that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It is available since go 1.11, with adding -trimpath flag build command.